# VixVM.LoginInGuest failure or insufficient permissions in guest operating system

Tags: vmware, vix

I'm using VixVM's API to log-in to VMs and perform actions.
I am able to log-in using a regular user account, but trying to do so using a domain user account, will issue the following error message:

> LoginToGuestAuthentication failure or insufficient permissions in
>   guest operating system

I am using the correct syntax of the function, that is `domain\username`.

I tried to google for the solution but i couldn't find a documentation regarding this. Does anyone know how to bypass this error ?

Comment: maybe you can Upgrade VMware Tools

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a mysterious 'Insufficient Permissions' error with VMWare fusion out of nowhere. After drilling down into the hosts' logs I uncovered the error:

`There is not enough space on the file system for the selected operation`

I had accumulated many old vms in .Trashes on osx which filled up the disk. Purging them resolved the error. Hope this helps